# The product of the commutator subgroup with any subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $G'$ be its commutator subgroup. If $H$ is any subgroup of $G$, is the subgroup $G'H$ normal in $G$?

I know that $G'H$ is a subgroup, as the product of a normal subgroup with any other subgroup is itself a subgroup. It's just the "normality" bit which I am struggling with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see this explicitly, without the correspondence theorem, as follows:

- Note that if $N\unlhd G$ and $H\leq G$ then $NH\leq G$ (this is an easy exercise). Hence, $G^{\prime}H\leq G$.
- If $g\in G$, $c\in G^{\prime}$ and $h\in H$ then $g^{-1}chg=(g^{-1}cg)(g^{-1}hgh^{-1})h$. As both $g^{-1}cg, g^{-1}hgh^{-1}\in G^{\prime}$, the result follows.

Comment: (Although I much prefer the proof using the correspondence theorem!)

Answer (score 10):

Yes. This follows from the [Correspondence Theorem,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem_(group_theory)) because $G'H/G'$ is a subgroup of the abelian group $G/G'$, so $G'H/G'$ is a normal subgroup of $G/G'$. Thus $G'H$, which is the full preimage of $G'H/G'$, is normal in $G$, which is the full preimage of $G/G'$.